# npm commain in Automator

Tags: automator, install, command-line

Hi,
I would like to write an automator workflow which allows me to install node packages.

I tried with

`$ npm insall`

but doesn't work any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: That looks a shell command you ran. So how have you tried from automator and what were the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you run shell command from Automator, it's `PATH` variable does have all the paths as when you run from Terminal. Use full path to npm executable. You can find the full path with `which npm` in the Terminal.

Comment: `which` is an external command. In any posix shell, you can use either of the following builtin commands: `type npm` or `command -v npm`

Comment: @fd0 I had `which` installed when I got the PC. :|